# Integrate xml into Classic ASP

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-3, asp-classic

I need to send a GET request in XML format to:
http://ip-api.com/xml

In order to get the following info:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query>
<status>success</status>
<country><![CDATA[COUNTRY]]></country>
<countryCode><![CDATA[COUNTRY CODE]]></countryCode>
<region><![CDATA[REGION CODE]]></region>
<regionName><![CDATA[REGION NAME]]></regionName>
<city><![CDATA[CITY]]></city>
<zip><![CDATA[ZIP CODE]]></zip>
<lat><![CDATA[LATITUDE]]></lat>
<lon><![CDATA[LONGITUDE]]></lon>
<timezone><![CDATA[TIME ZONE]]></timezone>
<isp><![CDATA[ISP NAME]]></isp>
<org><![CDATA[ORGANIZATION NAME]]></org>
<as><![CDATA[AS NUMBER / NAME]]></as>
<query><![CDATA[IP ADDRESS USED FOR QUERY]]></query>
</query>
```

I know nothing about XML, only about Classic ASP.

Any idea how can I integrate this XML code in my ASP page?

Comment: You say you want to integrate this code but say it's actually the information you need back. Which is it?

Comment: I'm confused myself :( I took it from here: http://ip-api.com/docs/api:xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the XMLDom to request and process the resulting XML.

Obviously think about catching any errors etc.

The code below just grabs the country - but should get you on your way

```
Set oXml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
with oXML
    .async = False
    .setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", true
    .load("http://ip-api.com/xml")
    set result = .selectnodes("query")
    response.write "Country: " & result(0).selectSingleNode("country").text
End with
```